# How to calculate averages and SEM in a multi-indexed pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have some data in a pandas dataframe which has a triple multi-index:

```
Antibody        Time Repeats          
Customer_Col1A2 0    1        0.657532
                     2        0.639933
                     3        0.975302
                5    1        0.628196
                     2        0.663301
                     3        0.921025
                10   1        0.665601
                     2        0.785324
                     3        0.697913
```

My question is, what is the best way to calculate the average and (sample) standard error of the mean for this data (grouped by time point? So the answer for the 0 time point would be `(0.657532+0.639933+0.975302)/3=0.757589` for the average and `0.188750216` for the SD. The output would look something like this:

```
Antibody        Time Average     sample SD
Customer_Col1A2 0    0.757589    0.188750216
                5    ....        ....
                10   ....        ....
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by the level of multi-index by specifying the `level` parameter, and calculate the average and SD using `DataFrame.mean()` and `DataFrame.std()` methods correspondingly:

```
df1.groupby(level=[0,1]).agg({'avg': 'mean', 'sd': 'std'})
```

[image]